# How to potentially pass null in as a parameter in ADO.Net

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm trying to pass a parameter into a stored proc using ADO.NET. This paramater is of type int but the field in the database is nullable. Here's my code:

```
AddInParameter(cmd, "@i_Required_License_List_PKID", DbType.Int32, RequiredLicenseListPkid==""? null : Convert.ToInt32(RequiredLicenseListPkid);
```

When I do this I get an error saying that there's no conversion between null and int.

I have also tried DbNull.Value in place of null but with the same result.

I can't seem to find any nullable parameter types in the DbType class but I wonder is that the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use:
   DBNull.Value;

as the value of the parameter

Answer (score 0):

**AddInParameter(cmd, "@i_Required_License_List_PKID", DbType.Int32, RequiredLicenseListPkid==""? DBNull.Value: Convert.ToInt32(RequiredLicenseListPkid);**